# Can issues pave the way?

Tags: phrase-usage

Another phrase-usage question, can you say :

```
These issues pave the way for new opportunities in several markets.
```

and does it sound sexy or weird ?

Comment: Sexy? In my lexicon, that's a total non-sequitur in this context. Perhaps you mean something different by "sexy" than I do? Like "cool" or "hip"?

Comment: yes, sorry. In french we say "sexy", it is also a non-sequitur - is it symbolic violence ? -  but it is "sexy" and sometimes poetic to associate an adjective to a noun that does not fit together ^_^

Comment: I don't really see how ***issues*** (which in such contexts normally means ***problems***) can "pave the way/smooth the path" to anything. So I'm guessing you mean *the **solving** of these issues*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trepidation is warranted in this case.

The reason this doesn't work perfectly is that the idiom “pave the way” is [defined](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pave+the+way+for) as:

> to be a preparation which will make it possible for something to happen in the future

“Be a preparation” is a strange phrase, but it is a crucial distinction here. It wouldn't be the issues *themselves* that would facilitate new opportunities. There would need to be someone solving the issues, and this person (or policy, or even the solutions) would be said to be paving the way.

Additionally, on the other side of the phrase, “new opportunities” presents another problem, albeit a lesser one. The fact that the opportunities are new makes it difficult to imagine the way to them having been paved by anything previous.

Nonetheless, the whole sentence could still be understood to mean

> *(Solutions to)* these issues pave the way for *(the creation of)* new opportunities in several markets.

so it *works* more or less, and would probably be understood, but might not be as “sexy” as you'd hoped.

Comment: I think you've pretty much covered the issues here, paving the way for OP to write more "naturally" (and hopefully less "sexily", since that's probably not appropriate to his context! :)

Comment: Thanks! I think “sexy” just means “poetic” in this instance (esp. based on OP's follow-up comment). As in “is this within the bounds of poetic license and appreciably evocative in its novelty (or is it just anguished English)?”

Comment: @ Tyler: Yes, that's what I assume OP means (or perhaps something more akin to *snappy, snazzy, jazzy,* etc.). But I'm guessing the context is some kind of business-oriented sales pitch or similar, where you'd probably want to sound sober/reliable rather than sexy/flighty.

Answer (score -2):

That is a pretty normal English sentence. The idiom "pave the way" refers to paving a road and means, ["to make it possible or easier for someone or something to follow."](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pave+the+way+for)

It sounds very businesslike and professional and has no unusual or sexual connotations.

Comment: Sorry, I'm with @FumbleFingers on this one. I don't see how *issues* could pave the way for anything. I wouldn't recommend the OP use this sentence, and without further context I'm not sure how we can advise.

Comment: Man, you haven't been around salesmen. Didn't you know that "problems" are simply "opportunities?" :-)

Comment: I think *issues* could fit.  It depends on the context, but unfortunately we don't know what that context is.

Comment: Right. I wrote my answer assuming that @hpid91 was accurately conveying the correct meaning. The full context would help a ton.